# DOTween capacity always increasing

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui, dotween

I'm creating a sequence and adding a couple of tweens to it. If I call it a couple of times the tweens capacity gets increased exponentially till everything gets incredible laggy.

I've recorded this 30 seconds gif to showcase the issue:

https://thumbs.gfycat.com/CarefulAngelicBrahmanbull-mobile.mp4

My code for when the button is pressed consists of 2 simple functions:

```
    public void HideUI()
    {
        Sequence sequence = DOTween.Sequence();

        sequence.Append(PremiumButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 300), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(SkinsButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 300), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(RateButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 300), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(HideShowUIButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(1145, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(AchievementsButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 300), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(CollectionsButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 300), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(SettingsButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 300), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(Up.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 400), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(Down.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, -400), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(LevelsPanel.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(2000, 0), 0.75f));

        HideUIImage.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = ShowUISprite;
        HideUIText.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "SHOW UI";

        HideShowUIButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => ShowUI());
    }

    public void ShowUI()
    {
        Sequence sequence = DOTween.Sequence();

        sequence.Append(PremiumButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(SkinsButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(RateButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(HideShowUIButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(AchievementsButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(CollectionsButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(SettingsButton.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(Up.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(Down.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.5f));
        sequence.Join(LevelsPanel.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0), 0.75f));

        HideUIImage.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = HideUISprite;
        HideUIText.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "HIDE UI";

        HideShowUIButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => HideUI());
    }
```

I don't understand what exactly is happening. Is there a memory leak? Why is DoTween increasing exponentially like that? The function suggested in the console has the prototype like static DOTween.SetTweensCapacity(int maxTweeners, int maxSequences). There's no way I'm reaching those numbers as the console shows.

Comment: Where do you remove the listeners after adding them, so that you don't call the function multiple times on subsequent clicks?

Comment: @DMGregory indeed i'm not removing the listeners and just keep adding them. Thank you!

Comment: If you're able to solve your problem with that, please post your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The issue as pointed out by @DMGregory was not actually with DoTween but with

```
    HideShowUIButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => ShowUI());
```

On every click I kept adding listeners over listeners and not removing the previous ones. At some point pressing a button would call the same function maybe tens of times forcing DoTween to perform hundreds of transitions.

You can solve it by removing a specific listener before adding a new one or by simply removing all. In my case I decided to remove all listeners:

```
HideShowUIButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
HideShowUIButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => ShowUI());
```

Comment: You could also wire up these listeners in the inspector, rather than adding and removing them at runtime.